# OnClick: Figure out which DOM element is clicked (get path)?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick, dom-events

**When an element is clicked: I want to know exactly which element it is.**

To ensure I'm not selecting multiple elements (e.g. with the same class) (and it may or may not have an id) I'm thinking about getting the absolute location/path in the DOM.

**Approach: I have two functions:**

1. `getDomPath`  - gets the path of a given element that is clicked

*return path of above function looks like this:*

```
html:nth-child(2) > body:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div#content > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div#mainbar > div#answers > div#answer-13326360 > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > pre:nth-child(2)
```

2. `testDomPathExists` - checks that the path from first function works
   **(test: I'm able to reselect this dom element using `document.querySelector(absolutePath)` )**

**PROBLEM: The path returned by  querySelector is null.** Doesn't matter what element in the dom doesn't work.

any ideas?

```
// Given element returns its path from body element
function getDomPath(el) {
  // var stack = [];
  // while (el.parentNode != null) {
  //   var sibCount = 0;
  //   var sibIndex = 0;
  //   for (var i = 0; i < el.parentNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
  //     var sib = el.parentNode.childNodes[i];
  //     if (sib.nodeName == el.nodeName) {
  //       if (sib === el) {
  //         sibIndex = sibCount;
  //       }
  //       sibCount++;
  //     }
  //   }
  //   if (el.hasAttribute("id") && el.id != "") {
  //     stack.unshift(el.nodeName.toLowerCase() + "#" + el.id);
  //   } else if (sibCount > 1) {
  //     stack.unshift(el.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ":eq(" + sibIndex + ")");
  //   } else {
  //     stack.unshift(el.nodeName.toLowerCase());
  //   }
  //   el = el.parentNode;
  // }
  // return stack.slice(1); // removes the html element
  // return stack;

  if (!(el instanceof Element)) return;
  var path = [];
  while (el.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    var selector = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if (el.id) {
      selector += "#" + el.id;
    } else {
      var sib = el,
        nth = 1;
      while (
        sib.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE &&
        (sib = sib.previousSibling) &&
        nth++
      );
      selector += ":nth-child(" + nth + ")";
    }
    path.unshift(selector);
    el = el.parentNode;
  }
  return path.join(" > ");
}

// TODO -
// function test that dom element path actually exists
// useful (so i can recreate it later)
function testDomPathExists(elementNodesArray) {
  let absolutePath = "";
  for (const i in elementNodesArray) {
    absolutePath += elementNodesArray[i];
  }

  console.log("test $$", absolutePath);

  var elem = document.querySelector(absolutePath);
  console.log("path element @@", elem);
}
```

Comment: There's probably a simpler way to do what you're trying to do. Wherever you're storing these paths, you could instead store the references to the actual elements. Then, if you want to make sure you're not already selecting it, just make sure the clicked element isn't in your list/set/whatever. The key to this is that the javascript API will always return the exact same element (not a copy) when you get one through the DOM API. e.g. `document.querySelector('body') === document.querySelector('body')` is true.

Comment: Problem is these paths (or element reference to location) will be saved to the database/persist so I can locate them later on (for various use cases) hence it can't be saved in memory - if that's what you mean

Comment: Even the path I am able to retrieve e.g. html:nth-child(2) > body:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div#content > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div#mainbar > div#answers > div#answer-13326360 > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > pre:nth-child(2)
  I should be able to locate it easily - seems not

Comment: That sounds even worse - if you ever change the structure of your webpage, (e.g. add a wrapper div to fix some CSS issue) everything stored in this table would become obsolete - but I'll assume you understand what you're doing, and see if I can find what's wrong.

Comment: Yeah i understand that :/ - for context, the use case: Its for a  web analytics; uniquely identify (and have some kind of persisted reference to) an element that is clicked (which may or may not have classes/ids) - so the only way would be using the path - so i think..

Comment: Ah, OK, sounds valid. Sorry to doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You're using nth-child wrong - I get it confused too.

If you have

```
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
</div>
```

and you want to select the second p tag, it's not `div:nth-child(2) > p` like you have it, its `div > p:nth-child(2)`.

nth-child is saying which child number that element is, not which child of that element to select.

Comment: So the getDomPath() function is broken - generating the path incorrectly?